# How to get appropriate data type value from mutation in Google Spanner?

Tags: java, google-cloud-spanner

1. In the code below I can get the appropriate data type value.

```
Map<String, Value> mutationMap = mutation.asMap();
Value locationValue = mutationMap.getOrDefault("location", null);
Long location = locationValue .getInt64();
```

2. How to get it within a loop?

```
new Gson().toJson(mutation.asMap().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,e->e.getValue().toString())));
```

In the above I'm converting everything to `string`. If the value has data type `int`, how do I get that?

Comment: Have you tried using [`instanceof` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs81/doc/en/portal/java-class/com/bea/p13n/expression/operator/Instanceof.html?skipReload=true)? `instanceof` operator is used to find whether the object is an instance of the specified type. Therefore, you can check whether the value is an instance of `int` type. If so, you can store the value into an `int` variable. For example:  `if ( obj instanceof int ) { int myObject = obj; }`

Comment: I have to check all columns in a row and it takes lot of operation.

Comment: I also notice that you are using `.toString()`, which is an inbuilt method in Java used to return the String object representing the value. For example, if `e->e.getValue()` is of `int` type, using `use e->e.getValue().toString()` will return the String object representing this Integer's value. Hence, you are converting everything into `String` datatype. So, it will depend on your use case, if you need to run the loop and print the values, `.toString()` is a good idea. On the other hand, if you would like to store the object into a variable, then there is no need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Value is defined as an Abstract class in Google Cloud Spanner Code
[Value.java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/Value.java)
It is overriden by Individual types.
So, using

```java
if (value instanceOf INT64) {
    return value.getInt64();
}
```

Would be the way to go.
I understand your concern about iterating over all data types.
You can either do that, or create a map of col name to type, and use that for better lookup.

I would also recommend using Jackson ObjectMapper to convert POJO to JSON, it may save some iterations.
It is not as optimized as "knowing" what you're about to use, but, it will solve your problem